# Is it possible to debug PhpUnit tests with --process-isolation option?

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug, phpstorm

For unittest

```
class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBreakpoint()
    {
        $a = 18;
    }
}
```

with breakpoint on line 5 "$a = 18;",

- Xdebug v2.1.0,
- PHPUnit 3.6.10,
- PHP 5.3.6,
- ubuntu 10.11

Running unittest with NO --process-isolation option stops script execution on the line 5, as expected.
Running the same configuration WITH --process-isolation option does not stop execution on line 5.

The option --process-isolation runs every test in new process using 'proc_open' in runJob function in https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Util/PHP.php

Tested with PhpStorm 3 and vim 7 with debugger plugin. It allows to debug PHPUnit itself, but not testcases.

Is there any way to debug the child process created by PhpUnit using Xdebug?  may be Zend Debugger?

Comment: I'm not setup for debugging in PHP Storm or VIM, so you will have to try this out. If you somehow can have environmental variables exits you could trigger Xdebug or ZendDebugger with those. Zend example QUERY_STRING="start_debug=1&debug_host=10.1.1.17&no_remote=1&debug_port=10000&debug_stop=1" /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/test.php (http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=130) . Xdebug example export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name" (http://xdebug.org/docs/remote). Let me know if that works.

Comment: @SamHennessy yes, it is exactly the way to debug CLI scripts. The environmental variables became existing after magic `export` command. It is not a problem to debug CLI scripts. As I mentioned, I can debug unittests when PHPUnit runs testcases in the same thread: `phpunit SampleTest` works like a charm. The `phpunit --process-isolation SampleTest` does not work. The last command creates 2 processes: the main PHPUnit, and a child for every test. I can debug the main process only, but not the child, and that's a problem.

Comment: My assumptions was that the user that PHPUnit was run under would be the same user as the user used by in the proc_open operation. If that's true then it should trigger an additional debug sessions. I don't know if VIM or PHP Storm can support multiple debug sessions. You may need to set the env vars in your profile to get it to work.

Comment: @SamHennessy You're right. The multiple debug sessions are not supported. [The issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7355#tab=History) has been created more than half year ago. It could be accepted as a correct answer.

Comment: Glad I could help you work this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments on the question. The issue is that [PHP Storm didn't support multiple parallel debugging sessions](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7355#tab=History).

Answer (score 2):

Go into PHPStorm Project Settings - PHP - Debug and set Xdebug to "force break at first line when script is outside the project".

It should break on some main() method and if you step over a couple of times (or press resume), it will reach your test.

Comment: **Yes:** it stops on first line of PHPUnit. As I was saying, there are no problem to debug PHPUnit itself either using remote debug listener, or local debugger (Shift-F9).

**No:** it will not reach my test.
If you do 'step over' or even 'step into' you do not reach the breakpoint in your test.  Debugger does not 'step into' child process created by [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect answer, but you can surround any block of code with xdebug_start_trace() and xdebug_stop_trace() calls to generate a stack trace for a targeted block of code. I've used this to see exactly what it happening at specific points in my unit tests when testing other peoples' code.

```
class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBreakpoint()
    {
        xdebug_start_trace('/tmp/testBreakPointTrace');
        $a = 18;
        xdebug_stop_trace();
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind that any failures will cause PHPUnit's exception handler to step in and cause the stack trace to look a little strange. If you are getting an error, you can get a clean trace by adding an exit; call right after xdebug_stop_trace:

```
class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBreakpoint()
    {
        xdebug_start_trace('/tmp/testBreakPointTrace');
        $a = 18;
        xdebug_stop_trace();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it is an option, as well as var_dump(). There are 2 problems: it requires to change code for debugging purposes, and it is not as  interactive as [visual debugger](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html#Visual_PHP_Debugger).   
The workaround I use at the moment is a unique group assigned to the test so running phpunit for this group make this test executed in isolation.