# Debugging PHPUnit Tests with Process Isolation On

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpunit, xdebug

I am testing a rather large application and it currently had 150+ tests being handled by PHPUnit. To keep PHP from running out of memory I have the `processIsolation` flag set to true. The problem is that when that flag is true, xdebug no longer works properly.

I am using VSCode, and normally, when I have it listening during PHPUnit tests, the stack traces show up on the left and I can browse around like expected. If I make the single change of setting the process isolation to true, then it just shows a couple of these: `Request 1 (3:52:48) Running`.

Here is my xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/Users/XXXXXX/.phpbrew/php/php-7.1.0-iconv/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
```

I am using the "PHP Debug" VS Code extension, and here is my `launch.json` configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug on Homestead",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "localSourceRoot": "/Users/XXXXXX/Sites",
            "serverSourceRoot": "/home/vagrant/Code"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: As I understand -- with `processIsolation` enabled PHPUnit creates separate processes for each test. In such case the "debug me" flag is not passed to them from the parent. So .. try with  `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` -- it will tell xdebug to attempt to debug every single request/process even without "debug me" command. Obviously, it's not super convenient for everyday use ... As possible alternative -- try also placing `xdebug_break();` in your code -- will act as programmatic breakpoint + will initiate debug session as well. Downside -- you have to remember to remove it later...

Comment: @LazyOne, unfortunately, neither of those work. I think PHPUnit manually disables Xdebug when running in isolation mode.

Comment: OK ... what xdebug log has to say then? Would be good to see if it tries to connect in those forked processes or not. Right now it could be that it does .. but your editor (debug client) simply does not support more than one simultaneous debug session (which I think might be the case with VSC)...

Comment: I've just tested it .. and it work in latest stable **PhpStorm** with **1)** 3 simultaneous debug sessions limit (instead of default 1); **2)** `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`; **3)** had to use "phone handle" icon as well (so IDE listens for debug connections that were not initiated by IDE itself) otherwise I see "connection timeout" in xdebug log when forked process tries to connect.

Comment: Initial ticket that gave hint about increasing the limit (that I had in mind to mention ... but in the end completely forgot to mention as you are using different editor/IDE) -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806805/is-it-possible-to-debug-phpunit-tests-with-process-isolation-option . I've tested using PhpStorm 2017.2.4 on Windows 10; PHP 5.6.31 nts x86; xdebug 2.5.5; PHPUnit 5.7.5 PHAR option (well, that my project does not use latest PHPUnit .. but it should be the same).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort in helping. I will look into your solutions as soon as I get a chance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to debug PhpUnit tests with --process-isolation option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806805/is-it-possible-to-debug-phpunit-tests-with-process-isolation-option)